# Calling a web service without using soap

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

I have a web service I'm converting it to wcf

I want to create a couple methods in the wcf... these will call methods in the web service

but I don't want to use soap or whatever because it is so slow

So I made a WCF service inside my web project.

Then I new up the web service and call a method...

Is it using soap? Is this just the same as calling any other method in the code?  Just as fast?  Is newing up the web service slow?

Comment: Pause, breathe, think, then rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default configuration of WCF is basichttpbinding. This is the same as an old web service(SOAP).

To send information in a binary format you need to configure WCF to use nettcpipbinding.